# TicTacToe code is not replacing numbers with O and X

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int square[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

void board();
int check_win();
int main() 
{
  char mark;//player 1 x player 2 0
  int player = 1, choice;
  int i = check_win();
  while(i == -1){
    board();
    player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;
    cout << "Player " << player << " enter a number";
    if(player  == 1)
    mark = 'X';
    else
    mark = 'O';
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        square[1] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 2:
        square[2] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 3:
        square[3] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 4:
        square[4] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 5:
        square[5] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 6:
        square[6] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 7:
        square[7] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 8:
        square[8] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      case 9:
        square[9] = (char)(int)mark;
        break;
      default:
        cout << "None of these";
        break;
    }
    i = check_win();
    player++;
  }
  board();
  if(i == 1) cout << "player " << --player << "win";
  else{
    cout << "Game DRAW";
  }
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}

int check_win()
{
  if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])

  return 1;
  else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])

  return 1;
  else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])

  return 1;
  else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])

  return 1;
  else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])

  return 1;
  else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])

  return 1;
  else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])

  return 1;
  else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])

  return 1;

  else
  return -1;
}


void board()
{
  cout << "\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n";
  cout << "Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)" << endl << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
  cout << "  " << square[1] << "  |  " << square[2] << "  |  "
  << square[3] << endl;
  cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
  cout << "  " << square[4] << "  |  " << square[5] << "  |  " <<
  square[6] << endl;
  cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
  cout << "  " << square[7] << "  |  " << square[8] << "  |  "
  << square[9] << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl << endl;
}
```

As you can see i finished the code for the game itself, but there is a little problem.
When i choose a number like `5` it's not changing `5` with `X` or `O`, it's used `88` and `79` instead, how to i resolve it?
Mark is the char variable that holds the memory for `X` and `O`, but i think that it got conversed by a function in here.

Comment: Instead of `switch (choice) {...` you could just do: `if (choice > 0 && choice <= 9) {square[choice] = mark;} else { cout << "None of these";}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you memorize numbers

```
int square[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

not `char`s

```
char square[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

and when you save the `X` (or `O`) in `square`

```
square[5] = (char)(int)mark;
```

you first convert `char` to `int` (`X` to `88`), then to `char` (`88` to `X`) and, last, you memorize it in an `int` (`X` to `88` again).

Suggestion: use a `square` array of `chars` and simply write

```
square[5] = mark;
```